# CMS driven components in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently have a NextJS site with several pages. Each page can have a number of components in any order. These components are driven by a CMS by whatever the end user chooses.

Example, they could have a carousel, followed by a grid, followed by paragraph component.

Each page I get initial props, which will have the list of components for that page, and the data for each component.

```
Page1.getInitialProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch('some api')
   const json = await res.json()
   return { data: json }
}
```

This ultimately reaches a top level parent component that looks at the data and renders the appropriate child component on the page with a switch statement

```
renderWidgets = (data) => {
  const pageWidgets = data.widgets.map((widget) => {
    switch(widget.type) {
      case WIDGETS.CAROUSEL:
        return <Carousel />;
      case WIDGETS.GRID:
        return <Grid />;
      case WIDGETS.PARAGRAPH:
        return <Paragraph />;
      default:
        return <div />;
    }
  });

  return pageWidgets;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="layout__main">
      {this.renderWidgets()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is if there is a better way to handle this this rendering component process. Each time a brand new widget is created I'll have to make sure to update the switch statement.  Is there a better way of rendering dynamic CMS driven components on a page?

Comment: What I would've done to improve it is to create a separate `Widget` React component accepting widget object and returning rendered widget. Like: `{this.props.data.widgets.map(widget => <Widget widget={widget} />))}`  You'll have to update renderer and switch cases, I don't think there's a way around that.

Comment: bad idea `import babel from 'babel-core';
const Component = eval(babel.transform('<Component />').code);`